# Single Node Hadoop setup in Ubuntu 12.0.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, ssh

I'm following the below steps to setup the `ssh` for running hadoop in single node, but, some how the when running `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` gives me an below exception trace, can any shed some light on this?

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install openssh-server
[sudo] password for hduser: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

> Package `openssh-server` is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source

```
E: Package 'openssh-server' has no installation candidate
```

solutions tried:

1 # update and install, no luck

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

2# which ssh, this not solution for this issue, but FYI,

which `ssh` gives below info,

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ which info
/usr/bin/info
```

whereas,

which `sshd` gives no path,

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ which sshd
hduser@ubuntu:~$
```

3 # fyi,

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ ssh localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
hduser@ubuntu:~$

hduser@ubuntu:~$ ssh -vvv localhost
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try below command from terminal for setting up ssh.

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
```